# Will tomcat run all the J2SE code too along with J2EE?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jboss, artificial-intelligence

I learned advance Java, in which servlet and JSP codes deal with the http request and response with the help of Tomcat server. I want to know whether tomcat will be able to run the code other than servlet and JSP, for example Java SE code, because I want to do some programming related to AI in Java at back-end. 
How can I implement AI in Java at back-end in my web project? Should I go for JBoss?

Comment: [WildFly](http://www.wildfly.org/) (the opensource version of JBoss) is nice, but it isn't clear that you need EJB(s) here.

Comment: Tomcat and JaveSE or JavaEE don't have anything to do with AI - they're completely independent. "How can I..." and "Should I..." questions are [not a good fit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for [stackoverflow's focus](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Tomcat is a Servlet container.t it does not execute any J2EE code whatsover. The whole thing runs in a JVM which by definition can execute any J2SE code. Your final question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow Prajjwal Gupta! Tomcat can execute written source code with Java SE.

Just as a grotesque example: if you, for example, execute the opening of a JOptionPane when the user makes the request, the code will execute, however the JOptionPane window will be displayed on the server and not on the client machine that is making the request.

This example is to remind you that the JSE code runs on the server side and not on the client side: the same thing will happen with your IA implementation.

As you yourself mentioned, Tomcat is an http server, so it receives a request, processes what should be done (its IA), and returns a response.

If your AI needs a lot of time to work on a response, consider returning on the response just an "OK, I'm processing" and when the processing is done, save the results to a database for further query.

Is that what you would like to know? If it was not, add more information so you can get a more objective answer ;)

Comment: Thank you for giving an answer for my question, otherwise someone has downvoted my question I saw. As a computer Science student, I recently started learning Java and Tomcat, so there are still too many confusions. 
Thanks again.